# How do I split results containing multiple columns into two rows each

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split my output into two rows for each rather than just one.  I'll eventually want to do an insert by looping through each one of these returns but one step at a time.

```
select m6.mrid
    ,'6' as 'FromProj'
    ,m10.mrid
    ,'10' as 'ToProj'
from master6 m6
left join master10 m10
    on (m01.mrtitle like '%40[%] load%' and m6.mrtitle like '%40[%] load%')
        or ((m6.mrtitle like '%ie11 know%' or m6.mrtitle like '%ie11 kr%') and m10.mrtitle like '%ie11 kr%')
        or (m6.mrtitle like '%survey issue%' and m10.mrtitle like '%survey issue%')
        or (m6.mrtitle like '%binary script%' and m10.mrtitle like '%binary script%')
        or (m6.mrtitle like '%zoom issue%' and m10.mrtitle like '%zoom issue%')
        or (m6.mrtitle like '%auto%submit%' and m10.mrtitle like '%auto%submit%')
where m10.mrtitle is not null
```

Results:

```
mrid   FromProj   mrid   ToProj
21     6          666    10
23     6          666    10
343    6          554    10
3432   6          222    10
5432   6          222    10
```

Desired Results:

```
mrid   FromProj
21     6 
666    10
23     6 
666    10
343    6 
554    10
3432   6 
222    10
5432   6 
222    10
```

Comment: Do a UNION instead of a JOIN.

Comment: And when you get to the insert portion of your project forget the idea of looping to insert data. You just need to use a select as the basis for your insert.

Comment: Your `WHERE  m10.mrtitle IS NOT NULL ` means that you get an `INNER JOIN` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `CROSS JOIN` the current result to row representations for '6' and '10' to get the row duplication, and then filter out the appropriate `mrid` (m6 or m10) with `CASE...WHEN`:

**Edit**

In order to preserve an interleaved order of the original values, move the original query into a derived table or CTE and assign an incrementing counter to each projected row (prior to the cross join). I've used `ROW_NUMBER()`, but you could also e.g. use a Sequence.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN x.FromProj = '6'
            THEN y.m6rid 
            ELSE y.m10mrid 
       END AS mrid,
       x.FromProj
from 
(SELECT m10.mrid as m10mrid, m6.mrid AS m6mrid, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m6.mrid ASC) AS rowOrder
 FROM master6 m6
  left join master10 m10
    on (m01.mrtitle like '%40[%] load%' and m6.mrtitle like '%40[%] load%')
        or ((m6.mrtitle like '%ie11 know%' or m6.mrtitle like '%ie11 kr%')
             and m10.mrtitle like '%ie11 kr%')
        or (m6.mrtitle like '%survey issue%' and m10.mrtitle like '%survey issue%')
        or (m6.mrtitle like '%binary script%' and m10.mrtitle like '%binary script%')
        or (m6.mrtitle like '%zoom issue%' and m10.mrtitle like '%zoom issue%')
        or (m6.mrtitle like '%auto%submit%' and m10.mrtitle like '%auto%submit%')
    where m10.mrtitle is not null
 ) y
cross join 
(select '6' as FromProj
 UNION
 select '10') x
ORDER BY rowOrder ASC, FromProj ASC; -- Since you want 6 before 10
```

Comment: Very close to what I want except it ordered by FromProj.  I need the lines to alternate with the FromProj and ToProj on adjacent lines.

Comment: By adding a row numbering to the original query (in the desired order) prior to duplicating the row with the cross join, you will then be able to sort the final cartesian product by this value (and the `FromProj`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on 2005+ you can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot this

```
SELECT ca.mrid,
       ca.FromProj
FROM   master6 m6
       INNER JOIN master10 m10
         ON ( m01.mrtitle LIKE '%40[%] load%'
              AND m6.mrtitle LIKE '%40[%] load%' )
             OR ( ( m6.mrtitle LIKE '%ie11 know%'
                     OR m6.mrtitle LIKE '%ie11 kr%' )
                  AND m10.mrtitle LIKE '%ie11 kr%' )
             OR ( m6.mrtitle LIKE '%survey issue%'
                  AND m10.mrtitle LIKE '%survey issue%' )
             OR ( m6.mrtitle LIKE '%binary script%'
                  AND m10.mrtitle LIKE '%binary script%' )
             OR ( m6.mrtitle LIKE '%zoom issue%'
                  AND m10.mrtitle LIKE '%zoom issue%' )
             OR ( m6.mrtitle LIKE '%auto%submit%'
                  AND m10.mrtitle LIKE '%auto%submit%' )
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT m6.mrid,
                           6
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT m10.mrid,
                           10) ca(mrid, FromProj)
WHERE  m10.mrtitle IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY mrid,
          FromProj
```

Comment: This gave me results in order of FromProj.  All 10s are listed then the 6s.

Comment: @RBC - `ORDER  BY mrid,  FromProj` certainly wouldn't do that.